# How to translate HTML code widget to Javascript format

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am new to coding but had a question I have this code:

```
<script class="scriptId_300x160_331391" type="text/javascript">
var ci_cap_scriptId = "331391";
var ci_cap_bid = "1472100001";
var ci_cap_format = "300x160";
var ci_cap_channel = "";
</script>
<noscript><p>Coupons powered by <a href="https://www.coupons.com? 
pid=13903&nid=10&zid=xh20&bid=1472100001">Coupons.com</a></p> 
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//bc.coupons.com"></script>
```

I am trying to figure out how to properly display it in HTML iFrame. My website is hosted through Wix.com and they only display code in this format any suggestions on what to add/edit in order for it to display? I've tried to play with it JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9rzrt5yL/1/) but it will show in HTML but not in Javascript (which is what I need for it to work)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is you can't due to [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

> Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks are a type of injection, in which malicious scripts are injected into otherwise benign and trusted web sites. XSS attacks occur when an attacker uses a web application to send malicious code, generally in the form of a browser side script, to a different end user. Flaws that allow these attacks to succeed are quite widespread and occur anywhere a web application uses input from a user within the output it generates without validating or encoding it.
>
> An attacker can use XSS to send a malicious script to an unsuspecting user. The end user’s browser has no way to know that the script should not be trusted, and will execute the script. Because it thinks the script came from a trusted source, the malicious script can access any cookies, session tokens, or other sensitive information retained by the browser and used with that site. These scripts can even rewrite the content of the HTML page. For more details on the different types of XSS flaws, see: Types of Cross-Site Scripting.

In you case, I think you should look on WIX documentation or ask for WIX support staff to help you out. I think they would have something for that somewhere.